# Knockout JS arbitrary objects binding and retrieving

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i'm still very new to knockout js so i've this

```
<script>
var Country = function(id, name, population) {
    this.id = id;
    this.countryName = name;
    this.countryPopulation = ko.observable(population);
};

var viewModel = {

    availableCountries : ko.observableArray([
        {id:1, name:"UK", population:100000},
        {id:2, name:"US", population:120000},
        {id:3, name:"UAE", population:802000}
    ]),
    selectedCountry : ko.observable() // Nothing selected by default
};  
//viewModel.selectedCountry(viewModel.availableCountries()[0]);
$(function(){ko.applyBindings(viewModel)});

</script>
```

and the view:

```
<p>
Your country:<select data-bind="options: availableCountries, optionsText: 'name', value:selectedCountry, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
</p>

<div data-bind="visible: selectedCountry"> <!-- Appears when you select something -->
    You have chosen a country with population
    <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry() ? selectedCountry().population : 'unknown'"></span>.
</div>
```

my question is i want the drop down to have a pre-selected value at initialization so i did this

```
viewModel.selectedCountry(viewModel.availableCountries()[0]);
```

which works good however the availableCountries array could come from a sever request which means the order of the objects are not known how do i retrieve an object from the availableCountries array whose name equals "UK" and set the selectedCountry to the object?
 i hope the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ko.utils.arrayFirst` returns the first element of an array that matches a condition:

```
viewModel.selectedCountry(ko.utils.arrayFirst(
  viewModel.availableCountries(), function(v) {
    return(v.name==='UK');
  }));
```

Comment: worked perfectly! so why is that function not documented in knockout's docs or did i miss it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function here to find the one item in the array you want.

```
var newItem = viewModel.availableCountries().reduce(function(a) { 
  if (a.name.toLowerCase() === "uk")
    return a;
});
viewModel.selectedCountry(newItem[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your request is completed you can find the item that is equal to "UK" and set the same way as you already do, I recommend you using a collection manipulation library or do it vanilla JavaScript, here some of the popular ones http://lodash.com/, http://underscorejs.org/